# Can you use any Bitcoin address as a Counterparty token receiving address?

Tags: wallet, address, colored-coins, counterparty

I have a bunch of bitcoin addresses and I would like to just use them for receiving counterparty tokens. I've read that counterparty addresses are the same thing as a Bitcoin address. Is this correct? And if so, doesnt this mean every Bitcoin address can effectively receive counterparty tokens?

I also can't seem to find an option to import an existing Bitcoin address into the counterwallet website. I was only able to find an import sweep option. screenshot would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use your Bitcoin addresses to receive Counterparty tokens. Make sure you have the private keys to your addresses backed up.

Counterparty is a layer built on top of the Bitcoin protocol which basically allows you to embed data into the Bitcoin blockchain. This data can be used to represent tokens which will be recognised by the counterparty protocol as being owned by a particular Bitcoin address. You will need a small BTC balance at the holding address in order to send those tokens to a new address.